# Regex to capture a deployment task

Tags: regex, powershell

```
Deployment task '[5.1.4] **Configure Redis, service bus and Update Databases and Samples**' 
with id '04d8e453-7f22-420d' and with scenario_id '9349bff9-9e41-4c26-9a90'
```

Given the above text, I need a regex which should give this output:

```
Configure Redis, service bus and Update Databases and Samples
```

Comment: Is the text always the same or do you want the text after **Deployment task '[x.x.x]**....?

Comment: I need a text after this ] brace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the text ends with a single quote, this is the regex you are looking for:

```
Deployment task '\[.*?\]\s*([^']+)
```

And here is an example how you can grab the value:

```
[regex]::Match($yourString, "Deployment task '\[.*?\]\s*([^']+)").Groups[1].Value
```